# Depth Buffer seems to not work - OpenGL Shader

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, glfw, depth-buffer

I'm using openGL with GLFW and GLEW. I'm rendering everything using shaders but it seems like the depth buffer doesn't work.
The shaders I'm using for 3D rendering are:

Vertex Shader

```
#version 410\n
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertex_position;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 vt
uniform mat4 view, proj, model;
out vec2 texture_coordinates;
void main() {
    texture_coordinates = vt;
    gl_Position = proj * view * model* vec4(vertex_position, 1.0);
};
```

Fragment Shader

```
#version 410\n
in vec2 texture_coordinates;
uniform sampler2D basic_texture;
out vec4 frag_colour;
void main() {
    vec4 texel = texture(basic_texture, vec2(texture_coordinates.x, 1 - texture_coordinates.y));
    frag_colour = texel;
};
```

and I'm also enabling the depth buffer and cull face

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER);
glDepthFunc(GL_NEVER);

glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glCullFace(GL_BACK);
glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
```

This is how it is looking:

- [The cube is being renderer first, because it is the first group of the Mesh and then the monkey is always renderer on the front, if I change the order of rendering, the cube is going to be in front](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcU7E.png)
- [Another example, you can see the ear of the monkey being renderer in the front](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bNVi.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not enabling depth testing. Change `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER);` into `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);` This error could have been detected using `glGetError()`.

Comment: @LuizAugustoWendt: Also, you used `glDepthFunc(GL_NEVER)`, which means the depth test will *never pass*. So all fragments ought to be culled. The only reason something appeared on the screen is because you enabled the wrong thing.

Comment: Yep, I was using never just to test if it the depth test was working :~

Answer (score 2):

Like SurvivalMachine said, change `GL_DEPTH_BUFFER` to `GL_DEPTH_TEST`. And also make sure that in your main loop you are calling `glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)` before any drawing commands.